# What is the python code to play limit orders on independent reserve bitcoin exchange?

Tags: python, api, bitcoin

What is the python code to place limit orders on independent reserve bitcoin exchange?

Here is my own written code, I keep getting the {'Message': 'Invalid credentials'} error. Anyone is able to help?

Official reference guide is here: https://www.independentreserve.com/API#PlaceLimitOrder

```
import time,hmac,hashlib,requests,json

key = 'test123'
secret = 'test321'

primaryCurrencyCode="Xbt"
secondaryCurrencyCode="Aud"
orderType="LimitBid"
volume=0.88
price=100

url = 'https://api.independentreserve.com/Private/PlaceLimitOrder'
nonce=int(time.time()) 
parameters = [url,'apiKey='+key,'nonce='+str(nonce),"primaryCurrencyCode="+primaryCurrencyCode,"secondaryCurrencyCode="+secondaryCurrencyCode,"orderType="+orderType,"price="+str(price),"volume="+str(volume)]
message = ','.join(parameters) 
signature=hmac.new(secret.encode('utf-8'),msg=message.encode('utf-8'),digestmod=hashlib.sha256).hexdigest().upper() 
data = {"apiKey":key,"nonce": str(nonce),"signature": str(signature),"primaryCurrencyCode":primaryCurrencyCode,
        "secondaryCurrencyCode":secondaryCurrencyCode,"orderType":orderType,"price":price,"volume":volume}
headers={'Content-Type':'application/json'} 
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data,sort_keys=True), headers=headers).content
response_body = json.loads(r.decode())
print(response_body)
```

Comment: Perhaps your credentials are invalid as the response says? Btw you can skip the json.loads(r.content.decode...) and just call r.json().

Comment: thanks for this tip

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Actually, I figured out the problem. Need to sort the parameters..

Working code for others reference:

```
import time,hmac,hashlib,requests,json

key = 'test123'
secret = 'test321'

primaryCurrencyCode="Xbt"
secondaryCurrencyCode="Aud"
orderType="LimitBid"
volume=0.88
price=100

url = 'https://api.independentreserve.com/Private/PlaceLimitOrder'
nonce=int(time.time()) 
parameters = [url] + sorted(['apiKey='+key,'nonce='+str(nonce),"primaryCurrencyCode="+primaryCurrencyCode,"secondaryCurrencyCode="+secondaryCurrencyCode,"orderType="+orderType,"price="+str(price),"volume="+str(volume)])
message = ','.join(parameters) 
signature=hmac.new(secret.encode('utf-8'),msg=message.encode('utf-8'),digestmod=hashlib.sha256).hexdigest().upper() 
data = {"apiKey":key,"nonce": str(nonce),"signature": str(signature),"primaryCurrencyCode":primaryCurrencyCode,
        "secondaryCurrencyCode":secondaryCurrencyCode,"orderType":orderType,"price":price,"volume":volume}
headers={'Content-Type':'application/json'} 
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data,sort_keys=True), headers=headers).content
response_body = json.loads(r.decode())
print(response_body)
```